# Why does changing an entire Array row create odd behavior?

Tags: java, arrays

Simply put. Why did this make my code malfunction after awhile.

```
//Color[][] colorArr = new Color[Width][Height]();

private void shiftRowsDown(int row) {
    for (int i = row; i > 0; i--)
    {
        colorArr[i] = colorArr[i - 1];//<--This in particular
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < colorArr[0].length; col++) 
    {
        colorArr[0][col] = null;
    }
}
```

while changing it to manually change one by one was fine.

```
private void shiftRowsDown(int row) {
    for (int i = row; i > 0; i--) {
        for(int col = 0;col < colorArr[i].length;col++)
        {
        colorArr[i][col] = colorArr[i - 1][col];//<--This in particular
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < colorArr[0].length; col++) 
    {
        colorArr[0][col] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: _Effective Java 2nd Edition, Prefer lists to arrays_. With lists, you don't have to do all this shifting etc. It's good to know how references (arrays or not) work, though.

Comment: Good book. In this case I used an array because the shifting modeled what the data was doing(This was for tetris). I should have just been thinking about it more. I even sidestepped the same problem in a different spot when doing colorArr[0][col] = null instead of colorArr[0] = null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, so your first code sets two elements of the outer array to the same inner array.

Simpler example:

```
Color[][] colors = new Color[2][2];
colors[0] = new Color[]{Color.red, Color.blue}; // colors[0] holds a reference to an array object, located at, say, 0xcafebabe
colors[1] = new Color[]{Color.orange, Color.yellow}; // Say color[1] a reference to an array at 0xdeadbeef
```

So you can visualize colors' memory like:

```
[0xcafebabe, 0xdeadbeef]
```

If you then do:

```
colors[1] = colors[0];
```

it is:

```
[0xcafebabe, 0xcafebabe]
```

The expanded structure is now:

```
{{Color.red, Color.blue}, {Color.red, Color.blue}}
```

But both rows are references to the *same* array, at the *same* memory position.  If you then do:

```
colors[1][0] = Color.yellow;
```

the array of arrays is still:

```
[0xcafebabe, 0xcafebabe]
```

and the expanded structure now looks like:

```
{{Color.yellow, Color.blue}, {Color.yellow, Color.blue}}
```

This is also called a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy).

Comment: Had I thought more about it, this would have been obvious. I think I was blinded by the bug this introduced. Very nice answer.